# How to add some text above the special Latex arrow `\hookrightarrow`?

Tags: latex

I wanna add some text such as `true:coin` above the special Latex arrow `\hookrightarrow`.Any methods I tried is doesn't work.

I use Latex in the markdown editor in web browser.

Both

```
$$\hookrightarrow^{xxx}$$
```

and

```
$$\hookrightarrow[]{xxx}$$
```

isn't work.

I want the result is that the `xxx` is abolve the arrow `\hookrightarrow`.

Comment: If i use `$$\stackrel{xxxx}\hookrightarrow$$`, it is ok.But the arrow can't auto extend by the length of text `xxxx`...How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry i get it.

Using `$$\xhookrightarrow[]{true:coin}$$`.It is useful.

Comment: Never use math mode for multi-letter words, this will mess up the kerning. You can for example use `\xhookrightarrow[]{\text{true:coin}}` instead.